# cannot access to userControl

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I working on a metro style project and I have 2 user controls.
when I run the project I get an error says that:"Page does not have any component with name "usercontrol"."

I dont write the classes in xaml files I used a new class page and linked them. and declare the component as `[UIComponent("btn")] public Button btn`; this goes for user controls as well.
I've checked my xaml and class files and user control components are there.
however when I checked `Page.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().ToArray<FieldInfo>();` I dont see the custom control components in xaml

how can I acess the custom controls in xaml??

Comment: do you have a string "usercontrol" in you xaml code?

Comment: yes 
I also solved my problem.
I have to use x:Name="" for userControl not Name=""